# Excel / VBA Behaves differently when stepping through code and running normally

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code which includes the functions `Worksheet_Calculate()` and `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` because I want to update some cells when any recalculation takes place as well as when I modify some particular cells in the sheet. Both of these subroutines call exactly the same subroutines. However, one of them works properly (Worksheet_Change) and the other (Worksheet_Calculate) does not, even though they both call exactly the same functions.

The next step I took was to set up breakpoints in places where I thought things went wrong when any recalculation took place, and to my surprise, the code executed by `Worksheet_Calculate()` worked properly this time (when stepping through the code by using breakpoints, etc). Aditionally, it will ocasionally work properly even in normal mode (not in debug), but this is very random. I have no idea what is causing this. Below is a shortened version of my subs (`MakeVisible`, `UpdateBaseline`, `UpdateDerivative1`... are all subroutines I defined later):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    MakeVisible
    UpdateBaseline

    If ([F4] > 0) Then
        UpdateDerivative1
    End If
    If ([F4] > 1) Then
        UpdateDerivative2
     End If
    If ([F4] > 2) Then
       UpdateDerivative3
    End If
    If ([F4] > 3) Then
       UpdateDerivative4
    End If


End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Application.Intersect(Sheets("Main").Range("C7:C61"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then

        MakeVisible
        UpdateBaseline

        If ([F4] > 0) Then
            UpdateDerivative1
        End If
        If ([F4] > 1) Then
            UpdateDerivative2
        End If
        If ([F4] > 2) Then
           UpdateDerivative3
        End If
        If ([F4] > 3) Then
            UpdateDerivative4
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

After spending some more time debugging, I believe that there is some **race condition** since the code in `UpdateBaseline`, `UpdateDerivative1`, etc. is actually resizing and moving some shape objects (such as stars, straight connectors, etc) and these get moved to the wrong place even though the variables I'm using to position them seem to have the correct value. My intuition tells me that moving shapes or changing their properties takes some computation that might be causing some race condition, but this is just a wild guess, it could be completely unrelated.

Thank you!

Comment: My other guess is that some of your code might depend on the current selection. For Example `[F4]` can return different values depending on what sheet is active/selected, but `[Main!F4]` will be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to identify the problem thanks to @Slai. The bug is indeed cause by a dependency of the code on the currently active sheet, but it wasn't fixed after I specified the sheet for particular cells (I changed `[F4]` to `[Main!F4]` and all other ocurrences.) I am still not able to figure out what the problem is since I made sure that all of my code specifically works with either `[Main!<Cell>]` or `Sheets("Main").Range("<Cell>")`, which would make any dependency on the currently active sheet dissappear. However, I added code to make the currently active sheet go back to "Main" when `Worksheet_Calculate()` gets triggered and this caused correct behavior. The code I added was `Worksheets("Main").Activate` on the first line of `Worksheet_Calculate()`.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
Dim ignoreEvents As Boolean 

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()

    If ignoreEvents = True Then Exit Sub
    ignoreEvents = True

    ' your code here 

    ignoreEvents = False
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If ignoreEvents = True Then Exit Sub
    ignoreEvents = True

    ' your code here 

    ignoreEvents = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Slai, thank you for your answer. However, the problem here is not whether the same code is executed twice or not. I tried adding this to the code but the behavior is identical. The behavior is different when in debug mode than normal mode without any changes in the code, I have done it multiple times now and I have no idea why. I used variable monitors too in the debugger and the variables are showing the exact same values when the subroutines are called from either `Worksheet_Change()` or `Worksheet_Calculate()`. Thanks!